# VueJS routing navigation not working when on dynamic route component

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, dynamic-routing

In my component I have the following vue-router routes one with a dynamic event of `'/event/:id'`

```js
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Dashboard',
            component: Dashboard
        },
        {
            path: '/events',
            name: 'Events',
            component: Events,
            beforeEnter: requireAuth
        },
        {
            path: '/event/:id',
            name: 'Event details',
            component: EventDetails,
            alias: 'test'
        }
    ]
```

When I visit an event ID url like this one: `http://localhost:8080/event/59f4906d8835582773ef769a` everything is fine and the event detail page is loaded. However if I try to navigate away from this component to for example the /events page the events component does not load and I stay on the same page.

The links I use to navigate away from the page are formatted with the `<router-link>` like this:

```
<router-link to="events">Events</router-link>
```

Comment: What does the url look like after you try to navigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `/` in route path.

Change this 
`<router-link to="events">Events</router-link>`
to `<router-link to="/events">Events</router-link>`

If you still have problem, check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/657f3twk/

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did I look over this, it's so obvious :-D

Answer (score 0):

Try exact links

```
<router-link to="/" exact>Home</router-link>
<router-link to="/events" exact>Events<router-link>
...
```